# Посимвольный ввод текста в форму браузера

Tags: c#

На неком сайте стоит некая защита от ctrl+c ctrl+v, т.е. определенный текст нужно набирать ручками.
Я нашел несколько способов реализации этого посимвольного ввода текста, но не в форму webbrowser'a, а в обычную форму винды и т.д.
Пробовал разбивать слово на буквы и их в массив, а далее через SendKeys вбивать вместе со sleep'ом после каждой буквы. Работает, но, увы, не практично, т.к. в это время нельзя заниматься ничем другим на ПК. Есть другие варианты решения?
Вот форма, в которую надо посимвольно забивать login

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("accountname").SetAttribute("value", login);
```

Comment: А если вызывать эту строку кода в цикле, меняя значение `login` - делая его длиннее на каждой итерации?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Пробовал, не помогло. Вот если бы была команда AddAttribute, которая бы уже к существующему значению прибавляла, допустим, переменную, тогда наверное бы сработало.